# Need help using Regular expression

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to display the only the highlighted values (They are 9 digits). Can we do this using RegExp?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_substr(column1, '[0-9]{9}')`. Below is an example:

```
select regexp_substr(column1, '[0-9]{9}') nine_digits
from (values
(';**260488570**;1;13.25;20339=22.99')
,('1293=::info::0,;**297100755**;1;2.86;20339=4.49')
,('1293=::info::0,;**338010030**;3;6.71;20339=2.69')
,('1293=::info::0,;**260142941**;1;2.38;20339=4.59')
,('1293=::info::0,;**370039059**;1;2.86;20339=3.79')
);
```

**Result:**

| COL2 |
| --- |
| 260488570 |
| 297100755 |
| 338010030 |
| 260142941 |
| 370039059 |